# Start slidingdiv script at the center

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, center

I have a script which i use for a project but have some weird problems with this.

- One problem with it is that I can't start at the absolute center, I can only start at a left: xx px position.
- Second problem is sometimes the moving background works and sometimes not. After refreshing. (try refresh F5, browser refresh symbol, home button) FF and IE9 works, safari and chrome doesn't all the time.

Here is the project: tinyurl.com/bogwvle/

Here is the script telling to start at xx position left.

```
$(function(o){  
    o = $("#overscroll").overscroll({
      cancelOn: '.no-drag',
            //hoverThumbs: true,
            //persistThumbs: true,
            //showThumbs: false,
            scrollLeft: 500,
            scrollTop: 200
        }).on('overscroll:dragstart overscroll:dragend overscroll:driftstart overscroll:driftend', function(event){
            console.log(event.type);
        });
        $("#link").click(function(){
            if(!o.data("dragging")) {
                console.log("clicked!");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

Does anyone knows how to fix one of these problems?

Comment: Well, most of times works, just 1 time it doesn't work and sometimes I get this at console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'is' of undefined`

Comment: Any idea's how to fix this :(

Comment: The issue with Chrome and Safari is solved, set off caching in the CMS helped